# Rails url helpers and optional routing segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Given the following route in `routes.rb`:

```
scope '/rest/messages(/new)', module: 'rest' do
  get '/moufa(/:id)', to: 'some_controller#some_action', as: :moufa
end
```

When in a rails console I try `app.moufa_url`, Then I receive `"http://www.example.com/rest/messages/moufa"`

BUT, When I do `app.moufa_url(id: 7)`, Then I receive `"http://www.example.com/rest/messages/new/moufa/7"`

I tried a few more routes and it looks like whenever one asks for a url for a route with parameters, the returned url includes the `/new` optional part but when no parameters are provided, it is omitted.

I went into the code of ActionDispatch and from there to Journey to figure out why this happens. Sadly as the synopsis of Journey warned me, it got really complicated really fast and I abandoned the yak shaving.

**Any ideas why the url helpers are behaving like this? Is it possible to force them to omit the optional segment?**

VERSIONS: Rails v3.2.17, Ruby v1.9.3

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and add the results to your answer?

Comment: Weird indeed, I also wonder why you need these two routes? I mean, if there is a legacy compatibility issue you should consider decoupling the two routes. amrv